# How does this duplicate checker loop work?

Tags: while-loop, java.util.scanner

Hi I hope someone can help. I'm trying to understand the following java program that loops until it finds two integers from the user that are the same:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whileloop {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int previous, input = in.nextInt();
    while(in.hasNextInt()){
        previous = input;
        input = in.nextInt();
        if (input == previous){
            System.out.println("Duplicate input found!");
        }
    }
}
```

So from my understanding, the program will call the user to provide two integers from .nextInt(), store those values in the variables named "previous" and "input", and then will proceed to the while loop. What I don't understand is what occurs right before the if condition. What is the point of having "previous" equate to "input" and then asking input for another integer? If I remove previous = input and input = in.nextInt() I get an error that says that the variables have not been initialized.... which confuses me since I thought that the variables "previous" and "input" got initialized when the program asked the user for the two integers? Evidently I'm quite confused, and would really appreciate help.

Comment: `int previous, input = in.nextInt();` does not initialize `previous`, only `input`.

Comment: Upvote to the above comment, but the assignment of `previous` to `input` is what logically allows you to compare the previous and current value.  If you don't see this, then maybe you should review a good programming tutorial.

Comment: Yup I see it. Thanks !